# Wannabe WebDev: HTML5&CSS3 vs. CSS frameworks

Tags: css, frameworks

As a new to web development i wonder, where should i start learning.

Should i start from a big good book on HTML5&CSS3 and hope, that FF and Chrome will support what i do, OR the whole world novadays doesnt write CSS themselves, and use help of JS-based CSS frameworks?

I think i wont be able to do a real world website in a year, so we must keep it in mind.

I hope, with modern browsers bit by bit support of new futures of HTML&CSS, many things can be done by native CSS3&HTML5 to the moment i 'graduate' w3school:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to web development, I suggest you stay away from CSS frameworks and concentrate on "basic" HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It is surprisingly easy to make a "real world" website with these basic tools. The whole world does NOT use CSS frameworks, most web designers do write the CSS themselves.

The best way to learn is practice. I would find something you are interested in and use that as a project to work on. Show off your knowledge and talent with whatever you are into!

You should be aware it will be many years before HTML5 and CSS3 are supported by all browsers, I expect that many will stick with IE8 for a long time since IE9 won't work with XP.

Answer (score 0):

you should start by getting a little project. Make random sites. Pretend you got a webdesign studio. Look at other sites. view their source. Get your hands dirty. W3schools is your best friend.

start with html,css then add javascript(jquery) then go serverside. you could do this backwards too.

thats how i started.
my 2 cents.

Comment: W3Schools is not your best friend. W3Schools is the kid who you think is your friend, but secretly sets you up to humiliate yourself at every opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are very simple. Being a good developer is having the experience to know how things work and when to apply what.

On the other hand jQuery is a library, thus like a real life library you are always reading. Learn how it works, and then learn to google regarding what you are looking for.

---

Don't skip ahead to HTML5 and CSS3, that's a lot like starting with a beta product, they are not yet standardised, but have been adopted (thus far) by the browsers.

### Analogy

A very good developer is a cowboy with his hand at his holster ready to whip out the perfect bit of code, due to experience and practice.

The novice has to get his gun out of bag, clean it, load it and aim it . As long as you are not going up against an expert your fire eventually, just hang in there.

**P.S.** Nearly forgot, the only point of framework ultimately is to increase the speed at which you can develop. If you don't know how it works it will only slow you down, and you don't need that on top of everything else.